# How Pass route() into datatables button like Edit and Delete

Tags: laravel-5, datatable, datatables

I have list table `pegawai` from DataTables and I have add edit and delete button into it but still static `<a href="pegawai/view/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'"` if user type manual and at the end there is `/` like `example.com/pegawai/` it will become `example.com/pegawai/pegawai/edit/{id}`
so I want use route() is it can ? because I've try it and just render string inside `class` tag

Here's my full DataTales code

```
public function data(Request $req)
    {
        DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));
        $pegawai = Pegawai::select(
            DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum'),
            "pegawai.id_pegawai",
            "pegawai.nama",
            "pegawai.nip",
            "pegawai.id_jabatan",
            "pegawai.id_unit_kerja",
            "jabatan.nama_jabatan",
            "unit_kerja.nama_unit_kerja"
            )
        ->Join("jabatan","pegawai.id_jabatan","=","jabatan.id_jabatan")
        ->join("unit_kerja","pegawai.id_unit_kerja","=","unit_kerja.id_unit_kerja");

        $datatables = Datatables::of($pegawai)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($pegawais) {
                return '
                <a href="pegawai/view/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                <a href="pegawai/edit/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> 
                <a href="pegawai/delete/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                <a href="pegawai/cetak_data/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                ';
            })
            ->editColumn('id_pegawai', '{{ $id_pegawai }}');

        if ($keyword = $req->get('search')['value']) {
            $datatables->filterColumn('rownum', 'whereRaw', '@rownum  + 1 like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        }

        return $datatables->make(true);
    }
```

How do I pass route() in DataTables like `<a href="{{ route("pegawai.edit", $pegawai->id_pegawai) }}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this pass route into datatables button

```
<a href="'. route("pengelolaan-surat.view", $pengelolaans->id_surat) .'"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your links should be:

- `pegawai/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'/show`
- `pegawai/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'/edit`
- `pegawai/'.$pegawais->id_pegawai.'/destroy`

Then Laravel should automatically pick these up if you've setup the routes correctly.